# Handling multiple perl scripts in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, perl

I have a lot of perl scripts that are on infinite loop running on my windows system. It is terribly inconvenient to have that many command prompts open not to mention the likelihood of closing them by mistake(strangely, they also seem to pause when I click on the prompt)

Is there someway I can handle this? Like maybe minimize this to the tray and maximize whenever necessary?

If it is of any use, I use activeperl

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) utility, which is a Windows console window enhancement, it has a multiple tab feature.

Answer (score 2):

Install GNU Screen. You can get it for Windows as part of [Cygwin](http://cygwin.com/). You can then have multiple command line shells running in a single window, and can detach that window to run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [Win32::Daemon?](http://search.cpan.org/~jdb/Win32-Daemon-20101014/Daemon.pm)

Comment: Even if i run it as a service, wont it still occupy the prompt?

Comment: I haven't used it but from what I've read (see link above), It shouldn't occupy a command window if you use the Win32::Daemon facilities to install it as a Windows service. I imagine you can then treat it like any service, started automatically at Windows startup or started manually when needed using the Windows service manager.